# stat missing operand error

Tags: linux, shell, stat

I want to find the entire path of an object on a remote machine where I know the last part of the path. Also I want to know its md5sum. I wrote a python script that will take a linux command as an input and execute it on a remote machine and then give me the output and error for that linux command. My problem is with the command. I am doing this:

```
stat -c '%Y %n' $(find / -path */foo/bar/filename.txt) && md5sum $(find / -path */foo/bar/filename.txt)
```

The error returned to me is:

```
stat: missing operand 
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Okay I was too quick to ask the question. There is nothing wrong with the command itself. The object  I was looking for was getting deleted before i ran this command.

Comment: Make that `find / -path '*/foo/bar/filename.txt' -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; -exec md5sum {} \;`. The quotes protect `*` from being expanded by the shell, and two `-execs` means you don't need to repeat the search twice.